# How can I use https://dev.gnosis-safe.io/ for local mainnet fork

Tags: gnosis-safe

When connected with my local chain I am being asked:

Because the interface doesn't depend on Gnosis infrastructure, you need to deploy the master copy and proxy factory yourself.

Although all the contracts are there, because it is a fork of the mainnet.

Comment: the dev interface currently always deploys a new set of contracts.

Comment: also the dev interface was only meant to be used for Safe App developers